Does the supposed domain separation make it safe to reuse Ed25519 public key for Curve25519 key establishment?
The "Similar Questions" section under my title suggest several similar questions on this, but none touched on that explicitly.
Because Montgomery curves have birationally equivalent Edwards curves (acknowledged in RFC-7748), it's possible to derive a Diffie-Hellman key establishment public key (yes, I'm conflating KEM/PKE/KEX since they're all functionally equivalent) from a EdDSA digital signature verification key. Such derivation is implemented in libsodium.
But is it safe? Is it recommended? Is the mathematical domain separation sufficient to make it safe?
@fgrieu mentioned that the security of such setup is protocol dependent. As an attempt at simplifying it all, let's assume it's a "jumbogram transmission protocol" (the jumbogram can hold things such as mails, and are transported like "reliable datagrams") where a group of users knows the EdDSA public key of each other sends jumbograms between them.
Starting from such protocol, what do we need to assume of it for it to be secure? What will happen if those assumptions fall apart one-by-one? What if we add assumptions? (so that we can derive generalizations to other protocols)

It is birationally,, Also, the Q need a heavy re-write at least your level.

I get the question as: Is it a security issue that Ed25519 signature and ECDH with Curve25519 use curves that are (birationally) equivalent? I think that depends on how the protocol turns (EC)DH into multi-users authenticated (EC)DH, and it's key derivation. Do you have a particular protocol in mind? By a meta-reasoning: for the protocol in libsodium, the answer must no!

@fgrieu Not a real-world protocol. Just an imaginary "mailing" protocol / message format that reuses the keypair.

@DannyNiu: in pure (EC)DH there are only ephemeral keys, so there is no key pair to share with a signature system. And in "mailing" the receiver is not involved in the preparation of the email, thus the functionality is (hybrid) public-key encryption. I now read the question as: is it safe to convert Ed25519 keys to Curve25519 keys and use both? The answer is protocol-dependent, so we assume an X25519 shared secret leaks, and wonder if that compromises Ed25519; or in the other way availability of an Ed25519 signing oracle.

@fgrieu edited.
